# How to access uploaded 3D model data when replaceing old API to new API in Autodesk Service Platform(Autodesk Forge)?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I already uploaded 3D models, manifests, and so on on Forge.
When you replace old API to new API, how can you access the uploaded data?
Also, it seems the old API is still working, Until when will it be usable?
I need some time to replace APIs.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The changes are only to the way a model is uploaded to OSS, the underlying storage remains the same.

We are turning off the old approach incrementally to avoid interruptions, thank you for making the necessary changes.

Comment: I see. so I don't have to change the way to access uploaded files, right? Thank you for your quick response!